# What is the coloring convention should I adopt for Buy and Sell

Tags: investing, starting-out-investing

This might be more of a UX question, but since it relates to buying and selling of stocks, I wanted to ask if there is a standard coloring convention for Buy and Sell like we have for Up (Green) Down (Red)

Comment: I work for one of the larger global trading software vendors ([Fidessa](http://www.fidessa.com)). We use blue for buy, red for sell. I can see the logic behind green, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would depend on your broker, but in most cases if they do use colours it would also be green for buy and red for sell (that has been the case with the brokers I have used where they do use colours for buy and sell in the order input box).

Comment: is it a standard convention to have green for buy and red for sell? it was less intuitive to me since buy means, your money is tied up, so what is the logic for being green.

Comment: Definitely green for buy. It is not uncommon to have a different color for shorts (i.e. buy to cover/sell short).

Comment: @ssinganamalla - The logic for buy being green, is that you are buying because you are after a stock that will rise in price. On the other-hand you would sell (or short sell) when you think the price will drop, so the colour would be red.

Comment: It's the opposite in China. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/except-china-which-country-will-use-red-for-up-and-green-for-down

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea - just checked with my wife, she says in the West red represents danger, whilst in Asia red represents good luck. This might be the reason for Red representing an up market in China.